# VBA copy content of cells under the same cells in a column

Tags: vba, excel

It's not my task working with VBA but I'm trying to learn something about it.

As the title says, I wanto to copy the content of cells of a column two times under those cells.

To be more clear I'll post an image in which ORIGINAL column are my column and RESULT column is what I need to achive.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Image at this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uSkq.png

Comment: You'll need to show what you've tried first before anyone will provide any help. Users are unlikely to help if no effort has been evidenced by the OP.

Comment: I didn't know that... The problem is that I can post some of the codes that I've used, but they didn't definely match my objective. Thank you for the advise by the way

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick:

```
Sub duplicateCells(column As Integer, firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer, duplications As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = firstRow To lastRow Step duplications + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, column).Select
    Selection.Copy
    For j = 1 To duplications
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, column).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

**column:** The column you would like this to run. In your example this is column '1'

**firstRow:** The row this routine should start. In your example this would be row '2'

**lastRow:** The last row this routine should process. In your example this would be row '8'

**duplications:** number of copies that should be made. In your example this is '2'

To run the example you should run

```
call duplicateCells(1, 2, 8, 2)
```

Make sure that the sheet is selected before your run this macro.

---

**Edit:**

Below an optimzed function, does the same but optimized as suggested by dave in the comments:

```
Sub duplicateCells(sheetName As String, column As Integer, firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer, duplications As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim sheet As New Worksheet

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)

For i = firstRow To lastRow Step duplications + 1
    For j = 1 To duplications
        sheet.Cells(i + j, column).Value = sheet.Cells(i, column).Value
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer would be far better if it didn't use `ActiveSheet`, `.Select`, `Copy` or `Paste` as none of those are necessary, and in the case where there are a lot of rows to work on, will significantly slow the macro down